# Installing and accessing chromedriver in aws lambda

Tags: python, selenium, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm making this application with the Alexa developer console that utilizes python selenium to help facilitate a user's interaction with the site via voice. My idea is to instantiate the driver upon the skill launch. I'm pretty new to AWS lambda, and unfortunately I'm unable to get the Chromedriver to install and work properly. I thought I could install it to the tmp directory and then try to access it from there, but for some reason whenever I pass the path into the webdriver, it returns a "cannot find Chrome binary error". Here is what I have:

```
turn = 0
chrome_options = None
browser = None
iframe = None 
input_element = None

def initialize():
    global turn
    global chrome_options
    global browser
    global iframe
    global input_element
    turn = 1
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=500,600")
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser  = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(path="/tmp").install(),chrome_options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/1g84m0sXpnNCv84GpN2PLZG/the-game-30th-anniversary-edition')
    time.sleep(10)
    iframe = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "IFRAME")
    browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'startgame').click()
    time.sleep(10)
    input_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'command-input-capture')

class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

     def handle(self, handler_input):
        speak_output = 'Hello'
        initialize()
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )
```

I believe it is correctly installing the chrome driver, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the path passed by ChromeDriverManager(path="/tmp").install() would be incorrect.

Comment: You've just installed the Chrome driver. I think you'd need to install chrome.exe itself too, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use EC2 for this.
You need to install chrome, virtual display (to fool chrome that it has a display).
Install all of those in an instance and connect it with other services. You should be good to go. This will also save your time a lot. Every time your lamdba runs, it does not need to install thing over again.

##### 1. open/connect to your instance.

You can use console or via ssh.

##### 2. install pip

`apt install -y python3 python3-pip`

##### 3. install python packages/libraries

`pip3 install selenium`

`pip3 install webdriver_manager`

`pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay`

##### 4. install chrome

- chrome dependency `apt install -y libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7`
- download chrome `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
- dpkg to install `dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb`
- if fails it fixes `apt install -y -f`

##### installing chrome driver

It is deprecated. No hard install is needed.

##### Test code

`python3 main.py test`